# Can there be a $C^1$ everywhere but $C^2$ nowhere function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Obviously examples of continuous-everywhere and differentiable-nowhere functions abundant. Similarly there are examples of [everywhere-smooth nowhere-analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) functions. And I'm well aware of the various differentiability properties of the family of functions
$$f_n(x) = x^n \sin(1/x), \quad n=0,1,2,\ldots$$
Namely that $f_2(x)$ is differentiable by not $C^1$ (etc. for higher values of $n$).

But a colleague just asked me if there are any examples of $C^1$ functions that are nowhere $C^2$, and I came up blank. I would imagine the same kind of construction could be asked about functions that are differentiable everywhere, but $C^1$ nowhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a continuous function which is differentiable nowhere, such as the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Then take an antiderivative of that function.

Comment: Hmm. Quite clever. I'm leaving this unanswered a tiny bit longer in case there are any other, more interesting examples. But thank you!